# python-mode: tab always indents with 2 spaces

Tags: indentation, python, file-local-variables

I start up my Emacs25 with `emacs25 -Q` to skip any init.el. When I then open a python file with local file variables as shown below, TAB indents only two spaces, instead of four:

```
# -*- mode: Python; python-indent-offset: 4; python-guess-indent: nil

for i in range(0, 10):
  print i

def f( i ):
  print i
```

What do I need to do, to get `python-mode` to honour the `python-indent-offset`?

Comment: Works for me, I get 4 spaces with that setup.

Comment: @npostavs try it again with my example. python-mode seems to be guessing the indentation. However, I asked python-guess-indent to be `nil`.

Comment: Furthermore, I just also tried `python-indent-guess-indent-offset: nil`, since `python-guess-indent` is deprecated. Still no luck.

Comment: Oh, seems to work if I add the missing `-*-` at the end of first line.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks! I was blind! Care to put it in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for file-local variables requires `-*-` on both ends (OP is missing the closing one); the following works correctly:

```
# -*- mode: Python; python-indent-offset: 4; python-guess-indent: nil -*-

for i in range(0, 10):
  print i

def f( i ):
  print i
```

Also of interest may be the commands `add-file-local-variable` (adds the variable settings to the end of the file) and `add-file-local-variable-prop-line` (adds the setting to the top line, thanks to Basil for pointing it out).

Comment: There is also `add-file-local-variable-prop-line` for this purpose.